# How to use JQuery to get the value property of a checkbox in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I want to use either Javascript or JQuery to get the value of a checkbox when it is checked.

How can I do that?  Please see question marks in the JQuery code below.

```
<html>
<body>

<form id="toggleForm" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>

<script>
$('**???**').on('**checked???**', function(){
   var checkedValue = $(this).attr('**value???**');
   console.log("The checkbox value property is "+checkedValue);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

(Please note that my question is not a duplicate of other questions, because in the other questions, the checkboxes have a class and the code is grabbing them using their class.  In my question, my checkboxes don't have a class.  How can I grab them without them having a class or ID??  How can I check their value?  What is the event called for when they are checked?  Please see the question marks in my attempt above.)

Comment: Maybe you need *radiobutton* instead of *checkbox* ?

Comment: use `.val()` like `var checkedValue = $(this).val();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery.

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('change','input:checkbox',function(){
var value=$(this).val();
if($(this).is(':checked')){
alert(value+" selected");
}
else{
alert(value+" unselected");}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

<form id="toggleForm" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `.val()`

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {

  var checkedValue = $(this).val();
  console.log("The checkbox value property is " + checkedValue);


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="toggleForm" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
($(this).prop("checked") == true) ? 
console.log($(this).val()+ " " +"checked"):console.log($(this).val()+ " " +"unchecked")
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="toggleForm" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>
```